# How to rename object keys inside array

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, ecmascript-6

I have an array of objects like this:

```
const customers = [
  {
    customer_name: 'Negan', 
    customer_age: 45, 
    customer_weapon: 'Bat',
    customer_email: 'negan@sanctuary.com',
    customer_city: 'Washington' 
  },
  {
    customer_name: 'Daryl', 
    customer_age: 41, 
    customer_weapon: 'Crossbow',
    customer_email: 'daryl.dixon@kickass.com',
    customer_city: 'Atlanta' 
  },
  {
    customer_name: 'Rick', 
    customer_age: 45, 
    customer_weapon: 'Magnum 357',
    customer_email: 'rick@alexandria.com',
    customer_city: 'King County' 
  },
]
```

and I want to replace all keys inside objects with these keys:

```
const newKeys = [
   'firstname',
   'age',
   'weapon',
   'email',
   'city'
]
```

What is the best way to do this? An example will be appreciated!

Comment: can you show us what you've tried please ? we're help to correct your flaws, not to give you code

Comment: note: everyone should be aware of the fact that any approach based on just a list of replacement keys is really limited to just a single kind of a customer object's key order (and structure). The environment always has to ensure the same key creation order for every single customer object.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can use `Object.values()` to retrieve values and then `array.reduce()` to compose a new object:

```js
const customers = [
  {
    customer_name: 'Negan', 
    customer_age: 45, 
    customer_weapon: 'Bat',
    customer_email: 'negan@sanctuary.com',
    customer_city: 'Washington' 
  },
  {
    customer_name: 'Daryl', 
    customer_age: 41, 
    customer_weapon: 'Crossbow',
    customer_email: 'daryl.dixon@kickass.com',
    customer_city: 'Atlanta' 
  },
  {
    customer_name: 'Rick', 
    customer_age: 45, 
    customer_weapon: 'Magnum 357',
    customer_email: 'rick@alexandria.com',
    customer_city: 'King County' 
  },
];

const newKeys = [
   'firstname',
   'age',
   'weapon',
   'email',
   'city'
];

let result = customers.map(obj => 
    Object.values(obj).reduce((acc, cur, i) => { 
       acc[newKeys[i]] = cur; 
       return acc; }, {}));

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 4):

I strongly suggest the usage of a key replacement map over a simple list of new keys, for the latter is strongly depended on a customer object's key order.

If a customer object satisfies a 1:1 key mapping, go for an approach similar to this one, that maps a list of customer objects by creating a new customer object with each iteration step via reducing a list of key tuples with each tuple holding the old and the new key ...

```js
function createNewCustomerFromOldOneViaBoundConfig(customer) {
  return Object.entries(this).reduce((newCustomer, [key, newKey]) => {

    newCustomer[newKey] = customer[key];
    return newCustomer;

  }, {});
};


const customerKeyReplacementMap = {
  customer_name: 'firstname',
  customer_age: 'age',
  customer_weapon: 'weapon',
  customer_email: 'email',
  customer_city: 'city'
};

const customers = [{

  customer_name: 'Negan', 
  customer_age: 45, 
  customer_weapon: 'Bat',
  customer_email: 'negan@sanctuary.com',
  customer_city: 'Washington' 
}, {
  customer_name: 'Daryl', 
  customer_age: 41, 
  customer_weapon: 'Crossbow',
  customer_email: 'daryl.dixon@kickass.com',
  customer_city: 'Atlanta' 
}, {
  customer_name: 'Rick', 
  customer_age: 45, 
  customer_weapon: 'Magnum 357',
  customer_email: 'rick@alexandria.com',
  customer_city: 'King County'

}].map(createNewCustomerFromOldOneViaBoundConfig, customerKeyReplacementMap);


console.log('customers : ', customers);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { min-height: 100%!important; top: 0; }
```

As soon as at least one customer object violates a strict 1:1 mapping of its keys, one has to change the approach to *creating **and** mutating* a new customer object from its outdated counterpart.

This case also proves that any approach based on just a list of replacement keys is really limited to just a single kind of a customer object's key order (and structure) ...

```js
function createNewCustomerFromOldOneAndMutateKeysViaBoundConfig(oldCustomer) {
  return Object.entries(this).reduce((customer, [oldKey, key]) => {

    customer[key] = customer[oldKey];
    delete customer[oldKey];

    return customer;

  }, Object.assign({}, oldCustomer));
};


const customerKeyReplacementMap = { 
  customer_name: 'firstname',
  customer_age: 'age',
  customer_weapon: 'weapon',
  customer_email: 'email',
  customer_city: 'city'
};

const customers = [{

  additional_key_1: 'FOO',

  customer_name: 'Negan', 
  customer_age: 45,
  
  additional_key_2: 'BAR',

  customer_weapon: 'Bat',
  customer_email: 'negan@sanctuary.com',
  customer_city: 'Washington' 
}, {
  additional_key_1: 'BAZ',

  customer_name: 'Daryl', 
  customer_age: 41,

  additional_key_2: 'BIZ',

  customer_weapon: 'Crossbow',
  customer_email: 'daryl.dixon@kickass.com',
  customer_city: 'Atlanta' 
}, {
  additional_key_1: 'FOOBAR',

  customer_name: 'Rick', 
  customer_age: 45,

  additional_key_2: 'BAZBIZ',

  customer_weapon: 'Magnum 357',
  customer_email: 'rick@alexandria.com',
  customer_city: 'King County'

}].map(
  createNewCustomerFromOldOneAndMutateKeysViaBoundConfig,
  customerKeyReplacementMap
);


console.log('customers : ', customers);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { min-height: 100%!important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 3):

You can iterate over the objects, and then change the `keys` of each property by the ones in `newKeys`:

```js
const customers = [
  {
    customer_name: 'Negan', 
    customer_age: 45, 
    customer_weapon: 'Bat',
    customer_email: 'negan@sanctuary.com',
    customer_city: 'Washington' 
  },
  {
    customer_name: 'Daryl', 
    customer_age: 41, 
    customer_weapon: 'Crossbow',
    customer_email: 'daryl.dixon@kickass.com',
    customer_city: 'Atlanta' 
  },
  {
    customer_name: 'Rick', 
    customer_age: 45, 
    customer_weapon: 'Magnum 357',
    customer_email: 'rick@alexandria.com',
    customer_city: 'King County' 
  },
]

const newKeys = [
   'firstname',
   'age',
   'weapon',
   'email',
   'city'
]

for (let i = 0; i < customers.length; i++) {
     let customer = customers[i];
     let j = 0;
     for(let p in customer){
          customer[newKeys[j++]] = customer[p];
          delete customer[p];
     }
}

console.log(customers);
```

Answer (score 3):

Map over the customers array and for each object in this array, iterate over its keys and add the values using these keys in a new object with the renamed property names. This way you will also avoid mutating original objects.

```js
const customers = [
  { customer_name: 'Negan', customer_age: 45, customer_weapon: 'Bat', customer_email: 'negan@sanctuary.com', customer_city: 'Washington' },
  { customer_name: 'Daryl', customer_age: 41, customer_weapon: 'Crossbow', customer_email: 'daryl.dixon@kickass.com', customer_city: 'Atlanta' },
  { customer_name: 'Rick', customer_age: 45, customer_weapon: 'Magnum 357', customer_email: 'rick@alexandria.com', customer_city: 'King County' },
];

const newKeys = [ 'firstname', 'age', 'weapon', 'email', 'city' ];

const res = customers.map(obj => {
  const newObj = {};
  Object.keys(obj).forEach((k, i) => newObj[newKeys[i]] = obj[k]);
  return newObj;
});

console.log(res);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

**A better approach** would be to make `newKeys` an object that maps old keys to new keys. This way you won't have to rely on the ordering of keys in the objects.

For this, just change `newKeys` to an object as shown below:

```
const newKeys = { 
  customer_name: 'firstname', 
  customer_age: 'age', 
  customer_weapon: 'weapon',
  customer_email: 'email',
  customer_city: 'city'
};
```

and change the code in the `.map()` method in above code snippet to

```
const res = customers.map(obj => {
  const newObj = {};
  Object.keys(obj).forEach(k => newObj[newKeys[k]] = obj[k]);
  return newObj;
});
```

Comment: @Milos ... in my opinion this should be the excepted answer since Yousaf's answer shows awareness of the pitfalls of any approach that is solely based on a simple key replacement list instead of any form of a key replacement mapping.

Answer (score 3):

You can try using [`for...of`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of) and [`for...in`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in) loop:

```js
const customers = [
  {
    customer_name: 'Negan', 
    customer_age: 45, 
    customer_weapon: 'Bat',
    customer_email: 'negan@sanctuary.com',
    customer_city: 'Washington' 
  },
  {
    customer_name: 'Daryl', 
    customer_age: 41, 
    customer_weapon: 'Crossbow',
    customer_email: 'daryl.dixon@kickass.com',
    customer_city: 'Atlanta' 
  },
  {
    customer_name: 'Rick', 
    customer_age: 45, 
    customer_weapon: 'Magnum 357',
    customer_email: 'rick@alexandria.com',
    customer_city: 'King County' 
  },
];
const newKeys = [
   'firstname',
   'age',
   'weapon',
   'email',
   'city'
]
for(var o of customers){
  var index = 0;
  for(var k in o){
    delete Object.assign(o, {[newKeys[index]]: o[k] })[k];
    index++;
  }
}
console.log(customers);
```

Answer (score 3):

You can do a simple map. This way the order of the keys doesn't matter.

```js
const customers = [{
    customer_name: 'Negan',
    customer_age: 45,
    customer_weapon: 'Bat',
    customer_email: 'negan@sanctuary.com',
    customer_city: 'Washington'
  },
  {
    customer_name: 'Daryl',
    customer_age: 41,
    customer_weapon: 'Crossbow',
    customer_email: 'daryl.dixon@kickass.com',
    customer_city: 'Atlanta'
  },
  {
    customer_name: 'Rick',
    customer_age: 45,
    customer_weapon: 'Magnum 357',
    customer_email: 'rick@alexandria.com',
    customer_city: 'King County'
  },
]

var updated = customers.map(customer => {
  const {
    customer_name,
    customer_age,
    customer_weapon,
    customer_email,
    customer_city
  } = customer;

  return {
    firstname: customer_name,
    age: customer_age,
    weapon: customer_weapon,
    email: customer_email,
    city: customer_city
  }
});

console.log(updated);
```

Answer (score 3):

Can be done in this way too.

```
const customers = [
    {
        customer_name: 'Negan',
        customer_age: 45,
        customer_weapon: 'Bat',
        customer_email: 'negan@sanctuary.com',
        customer_city: 'Washington'
    },
    {
        customer_name: 'Daryl',
        customer_age: 41,
        customer_weapon: 'Crossbow',
        customer_email: 'daryl.dixon@kickass.com',
        customer_city: 'Atlanta'
    },
    {
        customer_name: 'Rick',
        customer_age: 45,
        customer_weapon: 'Magnum 357',
        customer_email: 'rick@alexandria.com',
        customer_city: 'King County'
    },
]

const newKeys = [
    'firstname',
    'age',
    'weapon',
    'email',
    'city'
]

let newArr = []

customers.map(c => {
    let obj = {}
    Object.values(c).map((v,i)=>{
        obj[newKeys[i]] = v;
    })
    newArr.push(obj)
})

console.log(newArr)
```

Answer (score 2):

Two steps:

1. Create a new key with a value copied from an existing key
2. Delete the key you just copied the value from

**Working Example:**

```js
let myCustomer = {
  customer_name: 'Negan', 
  customer_age: 45 
}

myCustomer.firstname = myCustomer.customer_name;
myCustomer.age = myCustomer.customer_age;

delete myCustomer.customer_name;
delete myCustomer.customer_age;

console.log(myCustomer);
```

Answer (score 2):

Using destructuring with rename

```js
const update = (arr) =>
  arr.map(
    ({
      customer_name: firstname,
      customer_age: age,
      customer_weapon: weapon,
      customer_email: email,
      customer_city: city,
    }) => ({
      firstname,
      age,
      weapon,
      email,
      city,
    })
  );

const customers = [
  {
    customer_name: "Negan",
    customer_age: 45,
    customer_weapon: "Bat",
    customer_email: "negan@sanctuary.com",
    customer_city: "Washington",
  },
  {
    customer_name: "Daryl",
    customer_age: 41,
    customer_weapon: "Crossbow",
    customer_email: "daryl.dixon@kickass.com",
    customer_city: "Atlanta",
  },
  {
    customer_name: "Rick",
    customer_age: 45,
    customer_weapon: "Magnum 357",
    customer_email: "rick@alexandria.com",
    customer_city: "King County",
  },
];

const newKeys = ["firstname", "age", "weapon", "email", "city"];

console.log(update(customers));
```

Answer (score 1):

i have written this piece of code to satisfy all my needs on object property name changing.

```
deepRenameKeys = function(array: any[], shape: Object): any[] {
    if (!array || !array.length || !shape) return;
    return array.map(item => {
        let _obj = {};
        for (const key in shape) {
            if (shape.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
                _obj[key] = shape[key].split('.').length ?
                    shape[key].split('.').reduce((a, b) => a[b], item) :
                    item[shape[key]];
            }
        }
        return _obj;
    })
}
```

> Note that you can also use dotted notation :

```
const customers = [
    {
        customer_name: 'Negan',
        customer_age: 45,
        customer_weapon: {
            kind: 'Bat',
            type: 'melee'
        },
        customer_email: 'negan@sanctuary.com',
        customer_city: 'Washington'
    },
    {
        customer_name: 'Daryl',
        customer_age: 41,
        customer_weapon: {
            kind: 'Crossbow',
            type: 'range'
        },
        customer_email: 'daryl.dixon@kickass.com',
        customer_city: 'Atlanta'
    },
    {
        customer_name: 'Rick',
        customer_age: 45,
        customer_weapon: {
            kind: 'Magnum 357',
            type: 'range'
        },
        customer_email: 'rick@alexandria.com',
        customer_city: 'King County'
    }
];

const newKeys = [
    'firstname': 'customer_name',
    'age': 'customer_age',
    'weapon': 'customer_weapon.kind',
    'weaponType': 'customer_weapon.type'
    'email': 'customer_email',
    'city': 'customer_city'
];

let newData = deepRenameKeys(customers, newKeys);
```

Answer (score 1):

Another option using `replace` while looking for the properties names in the stringified `customers`, then parsing in back to JSON:

```js
const customers = [
  {
    customer_name: 'Negan', 
    customer_age: 45, 
    customer_weapon: 'Bat',
    customer_email: 'negan@sanctuary.com',
    customer_city: 'Washington' 
  },
  {
    customer_name: 'Daryl', 
    customer_age: 41, 
    customer_weapon: 'Crossbow',
    customer_email: 'daryl.dixon@kickass.com',
    customer_city: 'Atlanta' 
  },
  {
    customer_name: 'Rick', 
    customer_age: 45, 
    customer_weapon: 'Magnum 357',
    customer_email: 'rick@alexandria.com',
    customer_city: 'King County' 
  },
]

const newKeys = [
   {from: 'customer_name', to:'firstname'},
   {from: 'customer_age', to:'age'},
   {from: 'customer_weapon', to:'weapon'},
   {from: 'customer_email', to:'email'},
   {from: 'customer_city', to:'city'}
]


let str = JSON.stringify(customers);

newKeys.forEach(o=>str = str.replace(new RegExp(o.from, 'g'), o.to));

console.log(JSON.parse(str));
```